# Menu mobile style but also in desktop full height

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I try to develop my first Wordpress theme from 0 to the end.

The idea is to create a mobile style menu but also to display on desktop.

I already created it with jquery for apply the slide effect. This is the website where you can see and inspect the code (until is Wordpress website I can't copy and paste all the code). http://www.wolftrick.it/AREATEST/fripp/

I have the problem that the menu doesn't fit the height of the page. I tried a lot of different css codes (absolute/fixed position, different dispaly options) but I can't obtain the goal.

I also try to make the menu scroll if the height of the page is shorter than height of the menu.

I can change the html structure if is necessary to reach the result.

I copy and paste some portion of the code about the header.

I can change the html structure if is necessary to reach the result.

I copy and paste some portions of code about the header.

Jquery

```
jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).resize(function(){
            var winh = $(window).height();
            $('#wrap_all').css('min-height', winh);
            $('.menulist').css('min-height', winh);
        }).resize();
    });



    /* Slide menu function */
    $('#menu-btn').click(function() {
        var left = $('#wrap_site').css('left');
        var width = $('.menulist').css('width');
        if ((left == '0px') || (left == 'auto')) {
            $('.menulist').toggleClass('noshadow shadow');
            $('#wrap_site').animate({ left: width }, { duration: 600, easing: 'easeInOutQuad',});
        }else{
            $('.menulist').toggleClass('shadow noshadow');
            $('#wrap_site').animate({ left: '0' }, { duration: 600, easing: 'easeInOutQuad',});
        }
    });


});
```

CSS

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'HelveticaNeue', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: #555;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
#wrap_all {
    margin: 0 8%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrap_site {
    position: relative;
}
header {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 180px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<body class="home">

    <div id="wrap_all" class="container-fluid">

        <div id="wrap_site">

            <header class="row">

                <div id="menu">
                    <a id="menu-btn" href="#">
                        <i class="icon icon-menu"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/') ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo('name', 'display') ); ?>" rel="home">
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod('logo_fripp')); ?>">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div id="login">
                    <a id="login-btn" href="#">
                        <i class="icon icon-login-open"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <nav id="navbar">
                    <div class="nav menulist noshadow">
                        <h2 class="menu-title"><?php _e('Menu', 'fripplng'); ?></h2>
                        <div class="subtitle green"><?php _e('Where the travel begin', 'fripplng') ?></div>
                        <i class="iconmenutop icon-compass"></i>
                        <?php
                        $menu = array(
                            'theme_location'=>  'main',
                            'menu_class'    =>  'navmenu',
                        );
                        wp_nav_menu($menu);
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </nav>

            </header>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use height instead of min-height  at- $('#wrap_all').css('min-height', winh);  and set overflow:auto at class . menulist.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried but now there aren't any scroll of the page. I think it's determinate by the $('#wrap_all').css('height', winh); and the css #wrap_all {overflow:hidden}

Comment: ok I change also the .menulist height instead min-height. Now the menu look works good, the problem is the rest of the page. There isn't any scroll, cause the overflow:hidden on #wrap_all. If I apply overflow-x:hidden it's fine but I have the scroll bar on left of this div and not at the left of the browser.

Comment: menu and banner html code  include an parent div then apply  overflow:hidden.      remove #wrap_all overflow and height.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the `$(window).height()`, use `window.innerHeight` to get the current desktop height.

`window.innerWidth` to get the desktop width.

If you goal is something like this http://www.wolftrick.it/AREATEST/fripp/, just set the menu position to fixed, then use the `window.innerHeight` to auto set the height.

Lets say, your menu width is 300px? when you click the menu icon, add padding left of 300px and then slide the menu from left to right.

I'm sure you will have problem on the content if you add padding left 300px. Add `window.innerWidth` to the content holder then add css `box-sizing: content-box;`.

Hope this will help you a little.

Also check [WDES Responsive Mobile Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wdes-responsive-mobile-menu/) if you need a plugin.